# Disable flycheck for LaTeX

Tags: latex, flycheck

I use emacs with AUCTeX for editing tex files. I also use flycheck for some other programming language.

How to disable flycheck in TeX mode ? I tried called `flycheck-mode nil` in the latex hook  but it doesn't work.

Comment: This might help https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21042/disable-minor-mode-in-major-mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer from [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21042/disable-minor-mode-in-major-mode) :

Add it to your .emacs, after flycheck initialisations :
`(setq flycheck-global-modes '(not LaTeX-mode latex-mode))`