# Disable flycheck in XML files

Tags: flycheck, xml, nxml

When flycheck runs when I am editing largish XML files (I believe it is just nxml mode), it tends to slow things to a crawl and then I have to `kill emacs` since `C-g` only works for a fraction of second. If I get the chance to turn flycheck-mode off after I open the file everything is fine.

How do I disable it while keeping the global flycheck mode on?

---

These answers are close but I don't know what to fill in for the latex stuff, nor were the instructions for figuring this out helpful:

[Disable Minor Mode in Major Mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21042/disable-minor-mode-in-major-mode)

[Disable flycheck for laTeX](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/47009/disable-flycheck-for-latex)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the xml checkers to `flycheck-disabled-checkers`. For instance, if you are using `use-package` in your init file:

```lisp
(use-package flycheck
  :ensure t
  :config (global-flycheck-mode)
  (with-eval-after-load 'flycheck
    (setq-default flycheck-disabled-checkers '(xml-xmlstarlet xml-xmllint))))
```

will enable `flycheck` globally, but disable the (two default) xml checkers.

Alternatively, you could disable `flycheck` itself in `*.xml` files with:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("*\\.xml\\'" . (lambda () (flycheck-mode -1) (xml-mode))))
```

Or, you could [add a hook to `xml-mode`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847559/emacs-hook-for-when-opening-xml-file) (which is just an alias of `nxml-mode` in modern Emacs)

```lisp
(add-hook 'nxml-mode-hook  (lambda () (flycheck-mode -1)))
```

I personally use `use-package` and therefore the first method. Adding a hook to `nxml-mode-hook` would be the way to go otherwise. (Ab)Using `auto-mode-alist` for this is rather brutish, and probably frowned upon as bad style.

Comment: This wasn't working for me and I am trying to see if there is just something wrong with my config somewhere else before I accept