# Bind several minor modes together

Tags: evil, minor-mode

This has been driving me crazy, I can't get this to work. I want to link the on-off status of a handful of minor modes, in particular evil-mode, evil-quickscope-mode, hl-paren-mode, and a few others. I don't necessarily want evil globally, but once I turn on evil-mode I want the other modes to also turn on (and correspondingly turn off once evil turns off).

Is there a way to accomplish this cleanly? The closest I've come involved using mode-hooks, but somehow the modes always got out of sync (evil on, others off. others on, evil off. etc.)

edit: Posting the relevant mode-hooks section of my init.el:

```
;; Evil Mode Setup
(require 'evil-leader)
(evil-leader/set-leader ",")
(evil-leader/set-key "q" 'kill-buffer-and-window)
(evil-leader/set-key "b" 'ibuffer)

(defun after-all-loads () (require 'evil))
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'after-all-loads)
(define-key global-map "\C-xv" 'evil-mode)
(add-hook 'evil-mode-hook 'hl-paren-mode)
(add-hook 'evil-mode-hook 'evil-visual-mark-mode)
(add-hook 'evil-mode-hook 'evil-quickscope-mode)
(add-hook 'evil-mode-hook 'evil-leader-mode)
```

Comment: It sounds like you are on the right track with using mode-hooks. Can you post the relevant portions of your init file?

Comment: E.g., [`evil-quickscope-mode`](https://github.com/blorbx/evil-quickscope/blob/master/evil-quickscope.el) is defined via [`define-minor-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Minor-Modes.html). The doc for `define-minor-mode` says: "When called from Lisp, the mode command toggles the mode if the
argument is `toggle', disables the mode if the argument is a
non-positive integer, and enables the mode otherwise (including
if the argument is omitted or nil or a positive integer)."

Comment: I've edited the relevant portion of my init.el into my question. The issue I have specifically is that it works fine the first time I invoke evil, then I switch to a new buffer and evil stays on but the other modes all turn off. Then I have to toggle evil back off and on again to get the other modes back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be aware of whether a minor mode is global or buffer-local before you can reliably enable or disable it along with other modes. (See the list of mode types at the bottom of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/20915 )

(FYI, all of the following information was ascertained by checking the definitions of the various functions with `M-x find-function` -- although it helps to know what you're looking for, of course.)

`evil-quickscope-mode` and `evil-leader-mode` are buffer-local, so you can enable or disable them along with other buffer-local minor modes. I'm not sure where your `hl-paren-mode` is from, but I'll assume that's also buffer-local.

`evil-visual-mark-mode` is a *global* minor mode, so attempting to toggle it in specific buffers is wrong. You can probably enable this once and then not touch it (being a global mode, I would presume that it knows when `evil` is or isn't active). Assuming it's autoloaded:

```el
(eval-after-load 'evil
  '(evil-visual-mark-mode 1))
```

`evil-mode` itself is a *globalized* minor mode. That means it's a global mode which *controls* a buffer-local mode (this one is named `evil-local-mode`), and probably all of the interesting functionality is managed by the buffer-local mode. As such, I imagine you *actually* want to tie your other buffer-local minor modes to `evil-local-mode`.

```el
(defcustom my-evil-minor-modes
  '(evil-leader-mode
    evil-quickscope-mode
    hl-paren-mode)
  "Buffer-local minor modes to enable or disable with `evil-local-mode'."
  :type  '(repeat symbol)
  :group 'evil)

(defun my-evil-local-mode-hook ()
  "Enable or disable all of `my-evil-minor-modes' with `evil-local-mode'."
  (let ((state (if evil-local-mode 1 0)))
    (mapc (lambda (mode) (funcall mode state))
          my-evil-minor-modes)))

(add-hook 'evil-local-mode-hook 'my-evil-local-mode-hook)
```

You *could* copy and modify that for `evil-mode-hook` in order to enable/disable the global `evil-visual-mark-mode` along with the also-global `evil-mode`, but I don't think you actually want that, because you can enable `evil-local-mode` without enabling `evil-mode`.

Answer (score 2):

Just define your own minor mode that does what you want. It can turn on/off any number of modes when you turn it on/off. It can set variables, set up key bindings, and do pretty much anything you want.

IOW, you make a super-minor-mode that encapsulates whatever you want, including a bunch of other minor modes.

Turn on your new minor mode whenever you want - in your init file or on some hook or just interactively.

`C-h f define-minor-mode`